# Invalidate only a single item in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

Is there anyway to only invalidate a single item in a `ListBox`? There seems to be no method of getting the rectangle of an item, or even if a specific item is visible (aside from calling `IndexFromPoint` for every pixel in the control / at least every pixel in one column).

This is for C# WinForms (not WPF).

More information about what I am trying to do:

I have a `ListBox` with many items in it, and I want a set of "buttons" to appear on items that you hover over (such as a red X for remove). I have this working great,  except that on lists with 10 or more items, each time you hover over a new item it causes a visible redraw since I invalidate the entire control. The data is not changed, only the display is changed.

**Edit: More Information and Previous Attempts**

I already subclass `ListBox` and perform my drawing in `OnDrawItem` so protected methods of `ListBox` can be used.

I have tried the following with varying levels of success. The variable `this` is the extended `ListBox`, `index` is the item to drawn over, `old_index` is the item previously being drawn over.

```
// Causes flicker of entire list, but works
this.Invalidate();

// Causes flicker of selected item, but works
int sel_index = this.SelectedIndex;
this.SelectedIndex = old_index;
this.SelectedIndex = index;
this.SelectedIndex = sel_index;

// Does not work
if (old_index >= 0)
  this.RefreshItem(old_index);
if (index >= 0)
  this.RefreshItem(index);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I was being silly. Thanks to @LarsTech I decided to look over the entire list of `ListBox` functions again and found the appropriate one: `GetItemRectangle` and it is even public! I don't know how I missed this for the last hour...

The working solution is:

```
if (old_index >= 0)
  this.Invalidate(this.GetItemRectangle(old_index));
if (index >= 0)
  this.Invalidate(this.GetItemRectangle(index));
```

Which still produces a little flickering but significantly less (only visible when I mouse over many very quickly where before moving a single item caused it).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, this helped me with my flickering listbox. I also used: this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true); to help reduce the flickering as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to create your own version of the listbox by inheriting it and exposing the RefreshItem method that Microsoft is hiding from you:

```
public class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
  public new void RefreshItem(int index)
  {
    base.RefreshItem(index);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I believe its because the underlying data is not changing and/or list does not use DisplayMember.

Comment: Also, I am already inheriting from ListBox since I do my drawing in DrawItem. I will update my question with some more information.